# Is there a way to use Controller and View with different name yet still able to display error attribute messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-helper

I have a View that display a form of field to create new data, then send those data to another controller with different name to execute. The problem is by having different name, I can't display error messages for input field since they don't interact throught same view. I have tried sending Object model back to the view.

My Controller and View:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateBookHTMLHEPER(Book book)
    {
        if (book.bookTitle != "" && book.author != null)
        {
            _db.Books.Add(book);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create", book);
        }
    }
```

My cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateBookHTMLHEPER", "Book", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="border container" style="padding:30px;">
            <div class="hidden">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    Book Title
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.bookTitle, new { @class = "form-control", @value = @Model.bookTitle })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.bookTitle, new { @class = "form-control"})
                    }
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.bookTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    Author
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.author, new { @class = "form-control", @value = @Model.author })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.author, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    }
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.author, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-3 offset-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">
                        Create
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <a href="/Book/" class="btn btn-success form-control">Back To List</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Instead of `return RedirectToAction("Create", book);` you should do `return View("Create", book);`

Comment: Thanks. Sometime I wonder why I don't think of something that simple. You can write it down below and I will mark it as the answer.